# Auto incremento (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Quando eu dou `delete from` na tabela, depois dou `select`, volta a tabela sem `insert` nenhum, na hora que dou o `insert` novamente na tabela o id dos dados nao reiniciam do `0`.

Ou seja vem assim:

```
7 
8
9
```

Depois de dar delete na tabela e dar o insert novamente, ele nao vem assim:

```
1
2
3
```

Ele vem:

```
10
11
12
```

Comment: Quando for acrescentar algo, edite sua pergunta ao invés de comentar no próprio post.

Comment: Id é chave primária, não é pra voltar mesmo não. Se está em ambiente de teste e quer voltar, tem que ir na sequence e alterar manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é normal, o comando `DELETE` apaga registros mas não reinicia a semente do *sequence*.

O comando para alterar o valor da semente é esse:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1
```

Dai começa novamente a contar do 1

Comment: *Definitivamente* "rebobinar" a `SEQUENCE` é uma prática bastante perigosa e deve ser executada com bastatante cautela. Uma `SEQUENCE` serve par suprir a necessidade de `identificadores únicos` para determinadas informações, ao "rebobiná-la", os `identificadores` deixam de ser `únicos` e começam a se repetir!

Comment: Sim com certeza, aliás, o identificador é um campo deveríamos "esquecer" dele, ou seja, não se preocupar com o valor que tem lá, é algo que o banco deve usar para garantir um registro único. Apenas coloquei na pergunta para ilustrar a explicação, que apesar do comportamento do banco estar correto, é possível mudar o valor da sequence

Answer (score 1):

Não há nenhum problema nisso!

Um `chave primária` não precisa ser sequencial e nem mesmo começar em um valor específico para servir para o seu propósito. Uma `chave primária` precisa apenas ser um `identificador único` do registro, independente do que diabos ele seja.

A resposta do colega *@Ricardo Pontual* sugere o `RESTART` da `SEQUENCE` como uma possível solução, porém trata-se de uma prática bastante perigosa e deve ser estudada com bastatante cautela.

Uma `SEQUENCE` serve par suprir a necessidade de `identificadores únicos` para determinadas informações, ao "rebobiná-la", os identificadores deixam de ser únicos e começam a se repetir.

Agora me responda você: Qual o impacto de um auto-incremento que não começou a partir do número `1` no seu sistema ?